# C# .NET web app does not open (appears to be a .NET targeting issue)

Tags: .net, web-applications

I developed a .NET web app with Visual C# for Web (Express version) and a couple of weeks later had to reinstall Win7 on my laptop.
I then proceeded to install Visual Studio Professional and when I tried to open the project fun into the following message screen:
[image]

If I choose the first option, the project fails to load:

[image]

If I choose the second option, a browser tab is opened with the following URL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh487282.aspx

Since that last URL does not provide a link to install .NET Framework 4.5.1, I decided to search for it and download it from Microsoft's web site, which I did, but it didn't fix the issue.

Any thoughts, ideas, hints will be more than welcome.

**EDIT:** Both Visual Studio versions (Express and Proffesional) are 2012.

Comment: try installing .net frame work 4.5.1 through windows update

Comment: @Farrokh thanks for your message, but honestly I don't see what difference it would make. I already installed 4.5.1 manually and it didn't work. Is there anything in the link (see the post) I should install anyway?

Comment: check page title ".NET Framework SDKs and Targeting Packs for Visual Studio 2010". try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh487283